# Appending field from one layer into a different layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, attribute-joins, unique-id

In QGIS, I have one layer (called 'All data shapefile') which is a shapefile with my entire set of data, and another layer (called 'Y_data') that is also a shape file with a subset of 'All data shapefile'. The subset was determined by making a buffer around certain key data points and extracting all data points within 100m radius of the key points to make this second layer.

In the 'All data shapefile' layer I have a column named 'ID' which gives a unique number ID for each datapoint, however I added this column *after* creating 'Y_data', so the latter layer does not have the ID column.

How do I append the 'ID' column into the 'Y_data' layer, ensuring that each data point will have the same ID in both layers (i.e. each data point is given its correct ID as determined by 'All data shapefile')?

When I try to use 'Join', the pictures indicate what I end up with in my 'Y_data' attribute table:

[image: Join tool]
[image: 'Y_data' attribute table]

Comment: "Append" is usually an operation that adds *rows*. A *join* allows you to add *columns*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version A: Join attributes by location**

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Join attributes by location`. Settings to make (red highlighted on the screenshot):

- Set `Y_data` as `Base layer` and `All data shapefile` as `Join layer`
- Check the box next to `intersects`
- For `Join type`, select `Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only (one-to-one)`.

Optional settings (yellow on the screenshot):

- `Fields to add (leave empty to use all fields)`: select the `ID`-field.
- Optionally, you can set a `Joined field prefix` to better distinguish the initial attributes from the ones added by the join operation.

[image]

**Version B: field calculator**

You could also create a new field with field calculator on the layer `Y_data` and this expression:

```
attribute( 
     get_feature_by_id( 
        'All_data_shapefile',
        array_first (
            overlay_equals( 
                'All_data_shapefile', 
                $id
            )
        )
    ),
    'id'
)
```

Comment: I end up with "null" values in the column I have added when I try this

Comment: See improved answer

Comment: Ah, it seems I had chosen the wrong geometric predicate - choosing "equal" doesn't work, but "intersect" does. Thanks!

Comment: Great it worked for you! I added another method, using QGIS expressions with field calculator - just in case.

Comment: By the way: when asking questions, always add the software you use - I edited your question to add this information.